# how to change textView color when scrolled on same color background?

Tags: java, android

I have a textView that its color is white, but when I scroll this textView it comes to be above an imageView with the same color.
if I scrolled the textView and it entered that range of the dark image view, the text will not appear as its color is the same as the imageView, I want to change textView color when it gets above the imageView

[image]

Comment: Make it more clear

Comment: @SauravKumar edited now, if I scrolled the textView and it entered that range of the dark image view, the text will not appear as its color is the same as the imageView, I want to change textViewcolor when it gets above the imageView.

Comment: and how are you scrolling the textview?

Comment: I think scroll the textView above the ImageView is not a good idea, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @SauravKumar it is in a nested scroll view with other elements and activity background has colored portion from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used ScrollView like you did and retrieved the **Y** coordinates inside **addOnScrollChangedListener**
Upon reaching a specific number in **Y** coordinates, I will change the font color I want, and on return to the original coordinates, return the original color to him.

```
    //Definition of Object

    ScrollView scrollView ;
    TextView textView ;

      scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
      textView = findViewById(R.id.tx);
```

Use **getViewTreeObserver()** method of your **ScrollView**. here is
 an example :

```
    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

            int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY(); // vertical scroll position
            int scrollX = scrollView.getScrollX(); // horizontal scroll position

            if (scrollY <= 100 || scrollY == 150)
                textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue));

            else if (scrollY >= 151)
                textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.red));

        }
    });
```

> **Note:** These numbers are only available in the comparison for clarity
>   of example. You can change them according to your need .

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer to your question, but maybe a solution for your problem.

A white background with 50% transparency to your TextView. That way it will look the same in the white section and and it would make the text readable in the blue section.